# Multiple threads for run_in_executor

Tags: python-3.x

When wanting to execute these two methods, it is the same function that is not async, frame 2 is inserted into frame 1 and I don't know how I can send it through different threads so that they don't cross.

```
frame1 = {'data': 'hello'}
frame2 = frame1
frame2['data'] = 'bye' 

     executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
                sys.loop.run_in_executor(executor, MetodoInsertar, frame1)
    
    executorpush = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
                    sys.loop.run_in_executor(executorpush, MetodoInsertar, frame2)
```

I tried to put another name to the executor but it continues inserting the information of frame1 in frame2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After validating the issue it was that it was not copying frame1 to frame2 correctly to copy frame1 to frame2 must be done with `copy.deepcopy`

```
frame1 = {'data': 'hello'}
frame2 = copy.deepcopy(frame1)
frame2['data'] = 'bye' 

     executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
                sys.loop.run_in_executor(executor, MetodoInsertar, frame1)
    
    executorpush = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
                    sys.loop.run_in_executor(executorpush, MetodoInsertar, frame2)
```

In this way I got the expected result